How do I support old browsers in my create-react-app project?
I have an app that I built using create react app. I just found out that it needs to support a very old browser (chrome 37). I was under the impression that by default create react app uses babel to transpile the bundle to ES5. However, I am getting errors in chrome 37 because it looks like there are still arrow functions in the bundle. How can I configure my project to support browsers that don't support modern javascript, specifically Chrome 37?
note: I already have react-app-polyfill imported at the top of my index.js file and it has not resolved the issue
